# Issue with RecyclerView Adapter Attachment in Android App

Tags: android, kotlin

I am encountering an issue in my Android application related to the RecyclerView and its adapter. The error message I am receiving is "No adapter attached; skipping layout." I have thoroughly checked my code and XML layout files, but I'm unable to resolve the problem.
`2023-12-31 12:56:26.403 E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

XML Layout (relevant part):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_below="@id/btnGenerarAccion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/carga" />
```

Problem Description:

The RecyclerView in my Android application is configured in the XML layout with the appropriate attributes, including the layoutManager set to LinearLayoutManager.
Upon runtime, the application is throwing the "No adapter attached; skipping layout" error, indicating that the RecyclerView is not properly connected to its adapter.

Kotlin Code (GalleryFragment.kt):

```
package com.example.miauto.ui.gallery

import Vehicle
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.AppDatabaseVehicle
import com.example.AppDatabaseCarga
import com.example.CargaAdapter
import com.example.CargaCombustible
import com.example.miauto.databinding.FragmentGalleryBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.ZoneId

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private var selectedVehicle: Vehicle? = null
    private lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabaseVehicle
    private lateinit var appDatabaseCarga: AppDatabaseCarga
    private var _binding: FragmentGalleryBinding? = null
    private lateinit var CargaRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var spinnerAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>
    private var vehicles = mutableListOf<Vehicle>()

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val spinnerVehicles: Spinner = binding.spinnerVehicles
        val editTextLitros: EditText = binding.editTextLitros
        val editTextPrecio: EditText = binding.editTextPrecio
        val spinnerTipoCombustible: Spinner = binding.spinnerTipoCombustible
        val btnGenerarAccion: Button = binding.btnGenerarAccion

        // Inicializar Room Database
        appDatabase = AppDatabaseVehicle.getInstance(requireContext())
        appDatabaseCarga = AppDatabaseCarga.getInstance(requireContext())
        CargaRecyclerView = binding.recyclerView
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        CargaRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        // Inicializar el adaptador del Spinner
        spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
            requireContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            mutableListOf()
        ).apply {
            setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        }

        spinnerVehicles.adapter = spinnerAdapter
        selectedVehicle = if (spinnerVehicles.selectedItemPosition != AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            vehicles[spinnerVehicles.selectedItemPosition]
        } else {
            null
        }

// Configuración del adaptador del RecyclerView

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val listaDeCargas =
                selectedVehicle?.id?.let {
                    appDatabaseCarga.cargaCombustibleDao().obtenerCargasPorVehiculo(
                        it.toLong()
                    )
                }

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val cargaAdapter = if (listaDeCargas != null && listaDeCargas.isNotEmpty() && selectedVehicle != null) {
                    CargaAdapter(requireContext(), listaDeCargas, selectedVehicle!!)
                } else {
                    selectedVehicle?.let { CargaAdapter(requireContext(), emptyList(), it) }
                }

                CargaRecyclerView.adapter = cargaAdapter
            }
        }

        // Manejar la lógica cuando se hace clic en el botón "Generar Acción"
        btnGenerarAccion.setOnClickListener {
            val litrosInput: String = editTextLitros.text.toString()
            val precioInput: String = editTextPrecio.text.toString()
            val tipoCombustible: String = spinnerTipoCombustible.selectedItem.toString()


            // Validar que los campos no estén vacíos
            if (litrosInput.isNotEmpty() && precioInput.isNotEmpty() && litrosInput.isNumeric()) {
                // Obtener el vehículo seleccionado del Spinner


                // Obtener los litros de combustible
                val litros: Double = litrosInput.toDouble()
                val precio: Double = precioInput.toDouble()
                // Crear un objeto CargaCombustible con los datos capturados
                val cargaCombustible = CargaCombustible(
                    idVehiculo = 0,
                    litros = litros,
                    precio = precio,
                    tipoCombustible = tipoCombustible,
                    fecha = getCurrentDate(),
                    kilometraje = selectedVehicle?.mileage
                )

                // Guardar la carga de combustible en Room
                saveCargaCombustibleToRoom(cargaCombustible)
            }
        }

        // Cargar vehículos desde Room
        loadVehiclesFromRoom()

        return root
    }

    private fun loadVehiclesFromRoom() {
        // Limpiar la lista local de vehículos
        vehicles.clear()

        // Obtener vehículos desde Room en un hilo de fondo
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val vehicleEntities = appDatabase.vehicleDao().obtenerVehiculos()

            // Convertir VehicleEntity a Vehicle y agregar a la lista
            for (entity in vehicleEntities) {
                val vehicle = Vehicle(entity.id, entity.marca, entity.tipo, entity.modelo, entity.kilometros)
                vehicles.add(vehicle)
            }

            // Notificar al adaptador que los datos han cambiado (en el hilo principal)
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                spinnerAdapter.clear()
                spinnerAdapter.addAll(vehicles.map { "${it.brand} ${it.model}" })
                spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveCargaCombustibleToRoom(cargaCombustible: CargaCombustible) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // En tu código donde necesitas generar el próximo ID
            val ultimoId: Long? = appDatabaseCarga.cargaCombustibleDao().obtenerUltimoIdCarga()

            // El próximo ID será el último ID + 1, o 1 si no hay registros anteriores
            val nuevoId: Long = (ultimoId ?: 0) + 1
            cargaCombustible.idCarga = nuevoId
            appDatabaseCarga.cargaCombustibleDao().insertarCarga(cargaCombustible)
            println(cargaCombustible)
        }
    }

    // Función de extensión para validar si una cadena es numérica
    private fun String.isNumeric(): Boolean {
        return try {
            this.toDouble()
            true
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            false
        }
    }

    // Define tu lógica para obtener la fecha actual
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun getCurrentDate(): Long {
        val localDate = LocalDate.now()
        val instant = localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()
        return instant.toEpochMilli()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Request for Assistance:
I would appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue. The RecyclerView is expected to display a list of items, and I suspect there might be an error in how I am updating and attaching the adapter. Any insights or suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: As i can see you have not created a custom adapter for recycler view and have not attached the adapter with the recycler view. You have to create an Adapter class with view holder and the attach it in your activity like `recyclerView.adapter = adapter` where your adapter is a new Instance of custom Adapter class.

Comment: "CargaRecyclerView.adapter = cargaAdapter"

I got a adapter for the recicler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code flow leaves a lot of breakable places where it is very easy to get bugs and extremely hard to investigate.

First `vehicles` seems to be null at the time `selectedVehicle` is assigned the first time because you retrieve `vehicles` later in the method and within another GlobalScope coroutine. I assume the call to `spinnerVehicles.selectedItemPosition` return an invalid value too because `spinnerAdapter` has empty data at the time your create it. So in general: `selectedVehicle` is null

When `selectedVehicle` is null from this point, `cargaAdapter` is never created because you only create it when `selectedVehicle` is not null, and of course, you have an empty `RecyclerView`.

Some point you need to refactor your project I can suggest:

- Load `vehicles` list first, then assign the adapter to the spinner, then change the `selectedVehicle`. `selectedVehicle` stays null until now.
- Listen for `spinnerVehicles` selection changed event then change `selectedVehicle`.
- When `selectedVehicle` changed, retrieve data for `listaDeCargas` and then create the `RecylerView` adapter. The RecyclerView stays empty until now.
- Avoid using `GlobalScope` since you cannot control its lifecycle which may lead to crashes when the app goes to background.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, i fixt it with yours suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use viewModel to fetch data and observe changes in your fragment using live data or flow using an observer. and for your Fragment use first initialize your CargaAdapter() with an empty list and then assign

```
  val adapter = CarbaAdapter(context, emptyList(), vehicallist)
  binding.recyclerView = adapter
```

You don't need to use all unnecessary view references because you already use view binding and also remove LinearLayout code from a fragment. Now whenever your
data comes to your fragment observer method you have to update your adapter.